# Using sed with xargs

Tags: sed, xargs

```
echo './2d41d907b7cb558db6f3ca49e992ad8/rendering/02.png' | xargs -I {} cp {} `echo {} | sed s'/\///g' `
```

This gives me an error saying

```
cp: './2d41d907b7cb558db6f3ca49e992ad8/rendering/02.png' and './2d41d907b7cb558db6f3ca49e992ad8/rendering/02.png' are the same file
```

It is as if the sed is not working..

I ultimately want to do something like this

```
find . -name "*.png" | xargs -I {} cp {} ../`echo {} | sed s'/\///g' `
```

without using for loop or exec.

Comment: Basically, the `echo {} | sed…` part is evaluated before the xargs part. One solution is to create a new subshell. Also a few other tips: if you use `$()` instead of backticks, it's a lot more readable, and allows nesting. You can also use `sed 's,/,,g` or some other delimiter, which IMO is also more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code instead.

```
find . -type f -name '*.png' -exec sh -c 'echo cp "$1" ../"${1//\/}"' cp_sh {} \;
```

remove `echo` when you were happy with the dry-run result.